# How can I draw this figure in LaTeX

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

Can I use latex instead of office or Visio to draw the protocol shown below:

[image]

Please note there are pictures and some symbols I wanna like to write as in the final paper.

Comment: Why is `wrapfigure` tag here? Does it have to do something with `algorithms`? And why you don't just include the PDF from Visio and move on? (I know, it's not sportive, but it's the fastest solution.) Also, please show your attempts to do the figure in LaTeX as code.

Comment: welcome to tex.se! of course you can use latex package, for example `tikz` or `pstick` for drawing pictures. for examples see http://www.texample.net/

Comment: @Zarko Can I add an external picture to tikz

Comment: Yes, you can: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9559/121799.

Comment: @Zarako could you please see the picture on my question. I draw some thing like this in latex. so the symbols should be matched with my Paper.

Comment: If you already have a graphic file or a font for your symbols that you are using in the main body of your document, then you can just include the same ones in a TikZ picture.  The linked question shows you how.   But redrawing that golf buggy from scratch would be a waste of time and unlikely to look good.   If you want more help here, you should really have a go, then ask about specific problems when you get stuck.

Comment: Hello! I've got one answer. Can I post it in the comments?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/zgEdwpS

Comment: @current_user could u send me the Latex code you use instead of picture.

Comment: @Mohamed: Yes, but I guess just on e-mail, 'cause this question is putted on hold …

Comment: Okay this is my mail: mo.esmail100@gmail.com

Comment: @Mohamed: I send it …